# MongoDB not returning empty objects in document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've got this JSON snippet in a much much larger MongoDB document:

```
formConfig: {
  person: {},
  title: {name: 'title', ... },
  name: {name: 'name', ...}
}
```

However, when I then try to retrieve the document containing this JSON it doesn't return `person: {}` at all. All I'm getting is:

```
formConfig: {
  title: {name: 'title', ... },
  name: {name: 'name', ...}
}
```

Which completely breaks the frontend side of things since I need to know that `person` is there, regardless if it's empty or not.

When I search for this issue I can't find any similar questions or resources explaining why this happens in the first place, let alone how I can fix it.

So how do I fix it so it returns the `person` as well?

Here's the actual query, `appConfig` contains the JSON as mentioned:

```
exports.getSingle = (req, res, next) => {

  AppConfig.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
    .exec((err, appConfig) => {

      res.json({
        error: null,
        data: appConfig
      });
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: you can checkout the schema of AppConfig if there is anything called `select: false ` for person.

Comment: try to console.log req.params.id to check if the value is correct

Answer (score 1):

The issue was actually at `Schema` level, not using `minimize: false` in the `Schema` options cause empty objects to be removed.

This works:

```
new Schema ({...}, {minimize: false});
```